# How to convert a Base64 PNG image string to PNG Format in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting a base 64 string to an image and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it)

I have a PNG image encoded as a Base64 string. I need to convert this string into PNG format. How can I convert this in C#?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
using Convert=System.Convert;
using MemoryStream=System.IO.MemoryStream;
using Image=System.Drawing.Image;
//...

byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length))
{
  Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
  //TODO: do something with image
}
```

Comment: `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: Note that from .NET 6 and above System.Drawing will not be supported on Linux https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only