# Using base64 images in pdfsharp html to pdf conversion

Tags: c#, image, pdf, base64, pdfsharp

I am trying to embed base64 images in HTML which will then be converted to PNG, normal images work fine but if I set the src to a base64 string is shows the broken image in my pdf:

https://gyazo.com/7c86e05373b165840225e931cf5975c9

Here is an example of an image string I would send, works fine in the html, broken after converting to pdf.

```
<img id="fmacttcChartPNG-PullUps" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Does anyone know if this is supported or have any ideas on the correct direction to proceed on this?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDoc_FilelessImages.ashx) it's not supported: ""base64:" can be used with MigraDoc only, not with PDFsharp functions. Since PDFsharp can use images from streams, this is not a problem. For PDFsharp you can create a MemoryStream from the byte array and use this stream to create an XImage". I assume [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11464353/5095502) will allow you create the necessary stream that can be used by pdfsharp.

Comment: PDFsharp does not support the conversion from HTML to PDF. Conversion from HTML to PDF will be done by your code or by non-PDFsharp 3rd-party code. I assume you are using an undisclosed 3rd-party extension to PDFsharp. How can we know what it supports if we do not know what you are using?