# Vb.net How to get image from webbrowser to picturebox like this?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a image from webbrowser to imagebox.

İmage link likes this

```
<div id="aazone.OutputDiv" name="aazone.OutputDiv" class="noScrollbar">

    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgPI0/FTlWfjZ5Dnk+dJ
eAElFTkSuQmCC" style="border:1px solid #999999;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the Base64 representation in the src= attribute of the  element, so you can just split that out and get the image bytes. This is essentially answered in this post:

[converting a base 64 string to an image and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it)

All you need to do is some string work before hand to get your encoded png string.