# Image.Save method yields no result

Tags: c#, .net

My aim is to convert a base64 string into an image and save it to the disk. I have the following code (mostly from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5400225/2709929) SO answer) -

```
namespace ImageSaver
{
    using System;
    static class Program
    {
        public static void LoadImage()
        {
            //get a temp image from bytes, instead of loading from disk
            //data:image/gif;base64,
            //this image is a single pixel (black)
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");

            Image image;
            Bitmap bimage;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
                bimage = new Bitmap(image);
                bimage.Save("c:\\img.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ImageSaver.Program.LoadImage();
        }
    }
}
```

I ran it on MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (Windows 8.1 Pro x64), without errors, but I could not find the image file in C drive. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: are you sure? it works here and I get the image.

Comment: add this after calling `LoadImage` and see the result.             `Console.WriteLine(File.Exists("c:\\img.gif"));`

Comment: What happens if you use a different path that you definitely have unrestricted write access to (e.g. your documents folder)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, if the code does not have access to the path then it will throw an exception

Comment: @dotctor - I'm more thinking about the various redirection bits that are part of UAC - where access to some paths "succeeds" but ends up writing to completely different locations.

Comment: Perhaps place a try/catch round the save and see if anything pops up there.

Comment: have you considered having the correct permissions to write?

Comment: what do you mean by does not work? any error? are you running this code? are you refreshing the folder to see the changes?

Comment: try debugging the code, put a break point on `LoadImage` function and see whether it is called or not.

Comment: @dotctor I am running the code and repeatedly refreshing the folder to see the change. Also, `LoadImage` is being called alright.

Comment: try calling `bimage.Dispose()` after calling `bimage.Save(...)`

Comment: I believe it to be some kind of issue with write permissions. It works for folders inside the drive.

Comment: It did give a `A generic error occurred in GDI+` exception when tried on locations with restricted write access.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your file in this way:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\img.gif", bytes);
```

**EDIT**

Anyway put your code under try'n'catch to better understand why you file is not being saved.

Comment: The OP's code apparently "ran without problems", so there are no exceptions to inspect.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating LoadImage to this to find out what the error is, and set a debug point on the MessageBox to examine the full details of what's happening;

```
public static void LoadImage()
    {
        try
        {
            //get a temp image from bytes, instead of loading from disk
            //data:image/gif;base64,
            //this image is a single pixel (black)
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");

            Image image;
            Bitmap bimage;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            bimage = new Bitmap(image);
            bimage.Save("c:\\img.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```