# Uploading image from webcam to server

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

made a websitem, or trying to, where you can take a picture with your webcam and then upload it to the server, but ive found some inspiration in a guy that uses PHP and i wanna avoid it as much as posible. so what i have now in my .html for uploading is the picture is:

```
 // Upload image to sever 
        document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("images/", 0.85);
            $("#uploading").show();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "html5-webcam-save.php",
              data: { 
                imgBase64: dataUrl,
                 //user: "Joe"                
              }
```

and then the reference(html5-webcam-save.php):

```
<?php

$rawData = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$filteredData = explode(',', $rawData);
$unencoded = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);

 $datime = date("Y-m-d-H.i.s", time() ) ; # - 3600*7

//$userid  = $_POST['userid'] ;

// name & save the image file 
$fp = fopen('images/'.$datime.'-'.$userid.'.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $unencoded);
fclose($fp);
```

so my question, anyone now how to upload it to the server or just the "images" folder in the root of the site, without the need for PHP.

- to be honest, the reason i dont want the PHP is because i simply cant get it to work properly on the server side, and iam lost when it comes to php. So can this be done with for instance C#/Javascript?

Comment: You can't upload something to a folder on the server from the client side (javascript) directly.
You have to use PHP or any other server language.

Comment: may be this one can help you http://codingbin.com/capture-webcam-image-with-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"..without the need for PHP"

You can't. You need a server side language to receive the data from raw http, convert it back from base64 text to image and then write it to disc. It could be PHP, c#, nodejs javascript, but there will always be a server side controller handling all this. You can't access server file system from client javascript for obvious security reasons.

Comment: how would one go about doing this with C#? do you know?

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft More or less the same as in PHP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it