# How to save cropped image generated from Crop Box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, crop

I am using Crop box plugin to crop image and then upload it to server.

I used this sample : [Lightweight Image Cropping Plugin with jQuery - Cropbox](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Lightweight-Image-Cropping-Plugin-with-jQuery-Cropbox.html)

Sample working properly but how can I save cropped Image to server folder in ASP.NET web forms application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting a base 64 string to an image and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it)

Comment: Thanks It works properly now