# Convert base64 string to jpg/file

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding

I am struggling to find a way to convert a base 64 string to a jpeg or a file without using the Image class. Is it possible to create the file and not save it locally and upload to Azure blob storage?

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

Comment: What does "create the file and not save it locally" mean? "Pass it through" to where? Are you asking how to write the bytes to a file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5400225/713789

Comment: Seems like you could use parts from [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it).  I know you are using .NET Core, so if you want a great image library thats compatible take a look at [ImageSharp](https://sixlabors.com/projects/imagesharp/)

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, sorry. How do i pass it to a file so i can upload that file to blob storage.

Comment: @JayJay What does "pass it to a file" mean? Describe what you want to do using common terminology. You want to create a file but you don't want to save the data to a file. You need to be more clear, because you are saying two things that contradict each other.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I need it as an IFormFile so i can upload it to my storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it completely clean and simple, use something like this:

```
using (var img = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(img);
}
```

This creates a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream) that you can use to call [CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstream?view=azure-dotnet).

**Edit**
Or, like @mike-z said in the comment below, you can use [CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfrombytearray) directly.

Comment: There's also UploadFromByteArray, so no need to even create a stream.

Comment: Thank you sir! That makes a lot of sense. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @mikez true! That makes it even more clean!