# Adding Texts on the Image : A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, gdi+

i want to write 3 text on the specific image.
There isn't any problem on localhost.
But on the server,i try everything but nothing has changed.
always say:   A generic error occurred in GDI+.

if i write text on the image step by step,i got same error. After i add first text, second and third text can not be added on the image because of proccessing on the image with first text.

Summary:

First i want to add text1 on img1 and Dispose.
Second i want to add text2 on img1 and Dispose.
Third i want to add text3 on img1 and Dispose.

```
  using (Bitmap bitmapMasterImage = new Bitmap(stringMasterImageName))
            {
                using (Graphics graphicsMasterImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapMasterImage))
                {
                    graphicsMasterImage.DrawString(stringText1, new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(colorStringColor), new Point(233, 134), stringformatWriteTextFormat);
                    graphicsMasterImage.DrawString(stringText2, new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(colorStringColor), new Point(233, 210), stringformatWriteTextFormat);
                    graphicsMasterImage.DrawString(stringText3, new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(colorStringColor), new Point(233, 300), stringformatWriteTextFormat);
                }

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmapMasterImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    bitmapMasterImage.Save(stringOutPutFileName);
                    stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                }
            }
```

Thank You

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed) helps, viz keep the stream open for the lifespan of your bitmap

Comment: What line does it fail on? When saving the file, right?

Comment: no fail on localhost.it runs correctly.
Error on Server: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
So i dont know the line fail on

Answer (score 0):

This message usually appears when

- you don't have **write permissions** to save the file
- the path doesn't exists
- the file is in use

Comment: the file is in use.
i want to write 3 text on image.After adding first text on image,the image is in use.
Thats why i can not add second text and third text.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the paths setup the same way on the server (ie stringMasterImageName).  Also, this could be a permission/security issue.  [Look here](http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the brush streams

```
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(colorStringColor))
{
   ...         
}
```

Or use the built in brushes, these don't need to be closed.

```
graphicsMasterImage.DrawString(stringText1, font, Brushes.Black, new Point(233, 134), stringformatWriteTextFormat);
```