# a page that return image

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to make asp.net page return image to the browser here is the code

```
  protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        string iName = Request.QueryString.Get("ImageName") ;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("a.png"));
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        bmp.Dispose();
        Response.End();
    }
```

i works fine off line i mean when running it in visual studio but when running in godady hosting environment it gives this error

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +471002
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format) +36
   PageReturnImageDeals.MyImage.Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) +191
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055
```

Comment: You should used a [generic handler (.ashx)](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) for this.

Comment: Or use a binary stream to read the image file and write to the response instead of using Bitmap.

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed

Answer (score 1):

1) Why you retrieve iName when you don't use it ?

2) HttpHandler is better for this kind of action

3) there is no need to take any graphic action over file - its just plain transfer

Handler.ashx.cs:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {
  public bool IsReusable {
    get { return false; }
  }

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    var realPath = Server.MapPath("a.png");
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    context.Response.WriteFile(realPath);
  }
}
```

EDIT:

If you insist on having it as Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    var realPath = Server.MapPath("a.png");
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    Response.WriteFile(realPath);
}
```

Comment: the scenario is different but i made it simple in this question Ondrej

Comment: i tried this solution and it does work but how it can be done through a .aspx page and not in HttpHandler is it possible and why it is working on testing environment and not in production  environment ?