# Returning image created by Image.FromStream(Stream stream) Method

Tags: c#, image, stream, dispose

I have this function which returns an Image within the function the image is created using the **Image.FromStream** method
According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image

So I'm not closing the stream(if I do close the steam a GDI+ exception is thrown from the returned image object). My question is whether the stream will be **closed/disposed** when **Image.Dispose()** is called somewhere else on the returned Image

```
public static Image GetImage(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, offset, count);
    return Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
}
```

As suggested in one of the answers, **using** is not the way to go, since it throws an exception:

```
public static Image GetImage(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, offset, count))
    {
         return Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
   var image = GetImage(args);
   image.Save(path); <-- Throws exception
}
```

1. According to some people explicitly **disposing/closing** a **MemoryStream** is not necessary as it doesn't use any unmanaged resources others say the opposite thing so its kind of a dilemma.
2. **Image.Dispose** method doesn't dispose the stream ftom which the Image was created
3. The Image class doesn't hold any reference to the Stream passed to **Image.FromStream** method so the stream will eventually be collected by the **GC**...? Hence the exception in **Image.Save** method
4. Return a wrapper class which contains a reference to the stream and the Image created by it hence enabling us to **dispose** both of them...? or simply use the **Tag** property to keep a reference to the parent stream...?
5. This problem only seems to happen when using the **MemoryStream**. If the image is created from **ConnectStream** nothing **bad** happens even if the parent stream is disposed.

Comment: maybe providing some details would help us see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: see this question (and possible duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed

Answer (score 5):

Despite what others advice to do, you should not close or dispose the stream until the image is disposed.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

For some streams, like `MemoryStream`, disposing doesn't have much use since it doesn't allocate unmanaged resources. File streams on the other hand do, so unless you are very sure the stream is safe, you should always dispose the stream when you are done with the image.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only constructing an Image and then saving it consider this implementation instead:

```
  public static void GetAndSaveImage(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count,string path)
  {
      using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, offset, count))
      using(var img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
      {
          img.Save(path);
      }
  }
```

Comment: i don't really see the use of this... you are only opening an image to save it untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Disposing the image will not affect the memorystream as the following example demonstrates :

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

        byte[] contents = File.ReadAllBytes(DESKTOP_PATH + "asample.tif");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(contents);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        img.Dispose();
        Image img2 = Image.FromStream(ms);
        Console.WriteLine(img2.PixelFormat);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
```

This will output "Format32bppPargb". I suggest wrapping it into a using statement like so :

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(contents){
            // code here
        }
```

Comment: If I return the image from in between the using Image.Save will throw an exception

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem please provide concrete example of the usage please so it will clarify things.

Comment: your question was if calling the Image.Dispose() will dispose the stream... so this is the answer.

Comment: couldn't agree more but question is what is actually happening under the hood. Am I suppose the dispose that open stream?If so...how?

Comment: One effective way is to use the byte array as the image and wrap only build an image where you need it and after that dispose the stream, image and anything else that can be disposed.

Comment: "I suggest wrapping it into a using statement" This is bad advice according to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation which states that the stream must remain open until the image is disposed.