# A generic error occurred in GDI+ exception while uploading an image file

Tags: c#, image, exception, gdi+

I have already red some answers here on stackoverflow regarding this, but i just can't figure out which part am i disposing too fast:

[A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

[Image.Save(..) throws a GDI+ exception because the memory stream is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed)

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
image.Save(path, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);
```

Comment: which line does the error ocur?

Comment: @Micky this one: `image.Save(path, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);`

Comment: You'll get this exception whenever the codec has trouble writing the file.  A good debugging statement to add is System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "test") before the Save() call, it verifies the basic ability to create the file.  You'll now get a good exception that tells you what you did wrong.  Use MapPath().

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for saving me. I got this: `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Content\Images\23.jpg'.` The path was not the one i thought it would be. So that explains it all i think. Too bad that i didn't think of trying to write a file before myself. I feel stupid. :D