# A generic error occurred in GDI+ /// JPEG TrueColor (v1.1)

Tags: c#, jpeg

The following code works fine for almost all images but the one I attached raises this well know error.
The only difference this jpg has to other ones I have found with XnView, it says the format is "JPEG TrueColor (v1.1)" were other jpg files have "JPEG TrueColor (v1.2)".

Is this specific to that jpg version?

```
using (var originalFileStream = new FileStream(picturePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    var originalImage = Image.FromStream(originalFileStream);

    // ... some image resize ...

    var newFile = @"C:\Temp\temp.jpg";

    // we must keep the original stream open until saving http://stackoverflow.com/a/336396/1328536
    originalImage.Save(newFile);
}
```

edit 1: StackTrace:

```
bei System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
bei System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
bei System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)
bei Namespace.ViewModel.SavePicture(String picturePath) in d:\...\ViewModel.cs:Zeile 119.
bei Namespace.ViewModel.Edit() in d:\...\ViewModel.cs:Zeile 517.
```

edit 2: remove imgur link since the file was altered on upload

[link to zip file containing the jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrlKIXLp4dtTVI1ZnVhZHgwWHM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Works fine for me with the downloaded image. But I don't know whether the downloaded file is identical to your file (might have been altered by imgur).

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: added stacktrace... downloaded the file and that works... seems it is altered by imgur...

Comment: uploaded the file in a zip to my google drive

Comment: Also works with the image from the zip file. Are you sure that you can save to the specified location? Have you tried another folder / filename? The problem could of course also be related to the manipulations / resizing that you didn't include above.

Comment: Checked the same code you see above in an empty WinForms application. The result is the same error. Using Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 4 on Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, the problem might not be in your code but your environment. Have you checked that the path you're going to save to exists and is writable for your process? E.g. if the folder `C:\temp` does not exist you would get an `ExternalException` with a generic error message.

Comment: Tried it on two other machines and it works on Windows 8.1 but fails on Windows 7...

Comment: It looks like  a problem with your library. I tried several decoders and all had no problem reading the image. "JPEG TrueColor (v1.1)" has nothing to do with JPEG itself, that is something your encoder is adding.