# Convert Base64 String To Image Attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, base64, image-conversion

I have an image converted to a base64 string that I need to convert back to an image and attach to a `MailMessage`.

Here is the relevant code converting it from base64 string to image (I think I can skip the Image object and do this using one memory stream, but had some issues implementing that). Attempting to save the `Image` to a `MemoryStream` throws a generic GDI+ error:

```
Image image = ImageHelper.Base64ToImage(attachment.FieldData);

if (image != null)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); // Throws a generic GDI+ error on Save

        ms.Position = 0;

        var imageAttachment = new Attachment(ms, "image.png", "image/png");

        message.Attachments.Add(imageAttachment);
    }
}

public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String))
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to serve up the raw base64 string elsewhere using an img tag and it works fine so I'm confident that the problem isn't with the base64 string itself:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<myBase64StringHere>" alt="My Image" width="500" />
```

I must be doing something wrong in converting it back, but I haven't been able to figure out the issue. Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Are you sure the image has, "[`color management information embedded in the data stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4(v=vs.110).aspx)"? Maybe you only wanted to "validate the image", in which case use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6(v=vs.110).aspx) with `false` for the embedded color stuff: `Image.FromStream(ms, false, true);`.

Comment: I tried both `Image.FromStream(ms, false, true)` and `Image.FromStream(ms)`, but still get the same `A generic error occurred in GDI+.` error on `Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)`

Comment: Think I found your problem from reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed), you are not using `Bitmap`, but the same thing occurs with [`Image.FromStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx): "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image". You however are `using` the MemoryStream so it is disposed as the image is returned, and once that happens the `Image` is no longer usable. Maybe your static class needs to return `Tuple<Image, MemoryStream>`.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you so much! If you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Image.FromStream(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx) says, "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image", but your `using` statement disposes the stream as the Image is returned. A workaround would be to return both the image and the stream together as a tuple and without the `using`:

```
public static Tuple<Image, MemoryStream> Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String))
    {
        return null;
    }

    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)        
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

    return new Tuple<Image, MemoryStream>(image, ms);
}
```

Also note to take care and view each overload on the MSDN pages. Normally I would say, "view the most encompassing overload to get all the remarks and notes", but in this case that is not true. The MSDN page for the biggest overload, [`Image.FromStream Method (Stream, Boolean, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6(v=vs.110).aspx) does *not* mention that you need to keep the stream open, but I am fairly certain that is a mistake on that particular page.