# Image Converter not working

Tags: c#, bitmapimage, ivalueconverter

Can anyone explain why I am getting the error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

Here is the code:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Drawing.Image), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)value;
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmap.EndInit();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It is breaking on the `img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp)` line.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of saving to a stream, do so to a file.  Does that still throw the same error?  If not, can you open said file with an image viewer?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Save` method fails you should look at your source image that you pass to the method. How do you load/create this image? Maybe the image is already disposed or its internal stream was closed?

See this question and its accepted answer: [Image.Save(..) throws a GDI+ exception because the memory stream is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed)