# Error when saving image that was retrieved from DB

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Here is the situation:

1. I could Save() an Employee entry with a picture from PixPictureBox
   to the database.
2. If I edit the employee entry and change the picture from the
   PixPictureBox with a new one, the Update() goes fine.
3. This is where the error goes, whenever I edit an Employee entry and don't change the PixPictureBox's image, the `Update()` method throws the following exception:

> $exception    {"A generic error occurred in GDI+."}   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException

This error is firing from this method:

```
private byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This is my `GetParams()` method where `ImageToByteArray` is being used:

```
private void GetParams()
{
    Ebm.ResetParams();
    Ebm.Params.Id = IdTextBox.Text.GetInt();
    Ebm.Params.EmployeeCode = Ebm.GenerateEmployeeCode();
    Ebm.Params.LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
    Ebm.Params.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
    Ebm.Params.MiddleName = MiddleNameTextBox.Text;
    Ebm.Params.GenderId = GenderBox.SelectedValue.GetInt();
    Ebm.Params.BirthDate = BirthDatePicker.Value.GetDateTime();
    Ebm.Params.Age = AgeTextBox.Text.GetInt();
    Ebm.Params.Salary = SalaryTextBox.Text.GetDecimal();
    Ebm.Params.StatId = 1;

    if (PixPictureBox.Image != null)
    {
        Ebm.Params.Pics = ImageToByteArray(PixPictureBox.Image);
    }              
}
```

Here is the method I use to load the picture from the database to PixPictureBox

```
private Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] bytesArr)
{
   using (var memstr = new MemoryStream(bytesArr))
   {
          Image img = Image.FromStream(memstr);
          return img;
   }
}
```

This is how I load it:

```
private void LoadDetails()
{
    IdTextBox.Text = Ebm.Item.Id.GetString();
    EmployeeCodeTextBox.Text = Ebm.Item.EmployeeCode;
    LastNameTextBox.Text = Ebm.Item.LastName;
    FirstNameTextBox.Text = Ebm.Item.FirstName;
    MiddleNameTextBox.Text = Ebm.Item.MiddleName;
    GenderBox.SelectedValue = Ebm.Item.GenderId;
    BirthDatePicker.Value = Ebm.Item.BirthDate;
    AgeTextBox.Text = Ebm.Item.Age.GetString();
    SalaryTextBox.Text = Ebm.Item.Salary.GetString();

    try
    {
        PixPictureBox.Image = ByteArrayToImage(Ebm.Item.Pics);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PixPictureBox.Image = null;
    }

}
```

I also get this error from my MemoryStream which I think is related to the exception:

[image]

Comment: didnt change the picture, meaning, i loaded the picture from the db, so i just leave it as it is then click save, the error occurs on that imagetobytearray(). if i am trying to update an entry and change the picture (via open dialog box), the update goes fine. but if i just leave the picture (loaded from the db) as it is and didnt use another picture(via opendialog box), the imagetobytearrays throws exception

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the code where you get the image from the database and place it in the PictureBox control, we need to see that code.

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: The problem as I suspected is that you're disposing the MemoryStream [while you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336396/4934172). You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap and you should only dispose the bitmap itself after you're done with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image.Save(..) throws a GDI+ exception because the memory stream is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed)

Comment: i already tried using this var xs = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(xs, imageIn.RawFormat);
            return xs.ToArray(); but the same error occurs

Comment: Are you sure you didn't dispose the MemoryStream somewhere in your code? If so, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: apparently i did. it is in ByteArrayToImage()

Comment: When you assign the Image, in `private Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] bytesArr)`, Enclose the `Image img = Image.FromStream(memstr);` in an `using` block. Then return a clone of the Image: `return img.Clone() as Image;` or `return (Image)img.Clone();`

Comment: @PamingkasSevada I already told you what's wrong with your _current_ `ByteArrayToImage` method. If you have changed that and still have the same problem, please read what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, and provide one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change the `ByteArrayToImage()` method into this:

```
private Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] bytesArr)
{
    var mem = new MemoryStream(bytesArr);
    Image img = Image.FromStream(mem);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: @Mateusz Nope, that's the whole point. You should just dispose the bitmap when you're done, it'll close the stream for you. See [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336396/4934172) to the duplicate question.

Comment: I used Image, how can I dispose bitmap?

Comment: Just call `YourImageObject.Dispose();`. The `Image` class is [an abstract class which `Bitmap` inherits from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?). So, you can refer to the object as an `Image` or a `Bitmap`.