# How can I get all Files with a certain extension, without causing an IOException that tells me that the File I want to access is still in use

Tags: c#, image, dispose

I have created a Folder, let's name it `Input`. In there I have an `Input.png` and a `plugin.json`. Now I need to get the Image so I can put it into an Object of the Class `Module`.

I only have the folder as a whole dynamic path, the user can decide, where to put that folder. The foldername is also changeable. The image itself has the name of the folder it is in. So as I cannot just say

```
string image = path.Replace("C://Test//", "") + "Input.png";
```

I thought the best Idea to get the picture is by looking in the folder I currently am, store every file that ends with `.png` in a string-array, and just use the first index, as there will be only one .png in that folder.

In the end I want to delete that Folder, and that's where I get the IOException.
So I tried this:

```
using (string[] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png"))
{
    module.ModuleImage = Image.FromFile(imageFiles[0]);
}
```

But that tells me I can't do that, cause string[] is not disposable.

What can I do to close the png file when I don't need it, so I can delete the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using block is referencing the wrong thing

Image class implements IDisposable 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8

```
string[] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png")

 using (module.ModuleImage = Image.FromFile(imageFiles[0]))
 {
        // do your checks
 }
```

Comment: OP should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336396/3181933) if they are going to do that.