# How do I determine a mapped drive's actual path?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

How do I determine a mapped drive's actual path?

So if I have a mapped drive on a machine called "Z", how can I use .NET to determine the machine and path for the mapped folder?

The code can assume it's running on the machine with the mapped drive.

I looked at `Path`, `Directory`, and `FileInfo` objects, but can't seem to find anything.

I also looked for existing questions, but could not find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Check out @Nick's answer for a method that doesn't use pinvoke or any special libraries.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are some code samples:

- [Using P/Invoke](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/22)

All of the magic derives from a Windows function:

```
    [DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int WNetGetConnection(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string localName, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder remoteName, 
        ref int length);
```

Example invocation:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(512);
var size = sb.Capacity;
var error = Mpr.WNetGetConnection("Z:", sb, ref size);
if (error != 0)
    throw new Win32Exception(error, "WNetGetConnection failed");
 var networkpath = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I have confirmed the C# code from the link works. I would rather have a non-dll import version, but better than nothing at all.

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, can you please provide some context in your actual answer in case the link becomes unavailable? Thanks.

Comment: In case that link is invalid some day, the main thing you need to know is that it uses WNetGetConnection (you can find that on MSDN).

Comment: Here the saved github gist for the code in case the site stop working: 
https://gist.github.com/LuciferSam86/ea047f07ff95aa976b058848396f1be1

Answer (score 43):

I expanded on ibram's answer and created this class (which has been updated per comment feedback). I've probably over documented it, but it should be self-explanatory.

```
/// <summary>
/// A static class to help with resolving a mapped drive path to a UNC network path.
/// If a local drive path or a UNC network path are passed in, they will just be returned.
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// using System;
/// using System.IO;
/// using System.Management;    // Reference System.Management.dll
/// 
/// // Example/Test paths, these will need to be adjusted to match your environment. 
/// string[] paths = new string[] {
///     @"Z:\ShareName\Sub-Folder",
///     @"\\ACME-FILE\ShareName\Sub-Folder",
///     @"\\ACME.COM\ShareName\Sub-Folder", // DFS
///     @"C:\Temp",
///     @"\\localhost\c$\temp",
///     @"\\workstation\Temp",
///     @"Z:", // Mapped drive pointing to \\workstation\Temp
///     @"C:\",
///     @"Temp",
///     @".\Temp",
///     @"..\Temp",
///     "",
///     "    ",
///     null
/// };
/// 
/// foreach (var curPath in paths) {
///     try {
///         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}",
///             curPath,
///             MappedDriveResolver.ResolveToUNC(curPath))
///         );
///     }
///     catch (Exception ex) {
///         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}",
///             curPath,
///             ex.Message)
///         );
///     }
/// }
/// </example>
public static class MappedDriveResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Resolves the given path to a full UNC path if the path is a mapped drive.
    /// Otherwise, just returns the given path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to resolve.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ResolveToUNC(string path) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The path argument was null or whitespace.");
        }

        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("The path '{0}' was not a rooted path and ResolveToUNC does not support relative paths.",
                    path)
            );
        }

        // Is the path already in the UNC format?
        if (path.StartsWith(@"\\")) {
            return path;
        }

        string rootPath = ResolveToRootUNC(path);

        if (path.StartsWith(rootPath)) {
            return path; // Local drive, no resolving occurred
        }
        else {
            return path.Replace(GetDriveLetter(path), rootPath);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resolves the given path to a root UNC path if the path is a mapped drive.
    /// Otherwise, just returns the given path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to resolve.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ResolveToRootUNC(string path) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The path argument was null or whitespace.");
        }

        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("The path '{0}' was not a rooted path and ResolveToRootUNC does not support relative paths.",
                path)
            );
        }

        if (path.StartsWith(@"\\")) {
            return Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path);
        }

        // Get just the drive letter for WMI call
        string driveletter = GetDriveLetter(path);

        // Query WMI if the drive letter is a network drive, and if so the UNC path for it
        using (ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject()) {
            mo.Path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", driveletter));

            DriveType driveType = (DriveType)((uint)mo["DriveType"]);
            string networkRoot = Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]);

            if (driveType == DriveType.Network) {
                return networkRoot;
            }
            else {
                return driveletter + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            }
        }           
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the given path is a network drive.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to check.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool isNetworkDrive(string path) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The path argument was null or whitespace.");
        }

        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("The path '{0}' was not a rooted path and ResolveToRootUNC does not support relative paths.",
                path)
            );
        }

        if (path.StartsWith(@"\\")) {
            return true;
        }

        // Get just the drive letter for WMI call
        string driveletter = GetDriveLetter(path);

        // Query WMI if the drive letter is a network drive
        using (ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject()) {
            mo.Path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", driveletter));
            DriveType driveType = (DriveType)((uint)mo["DriveType"]);
            return driveType == DriveType.Network;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Given a path will extract just the drive letter with volume separator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <returns>C:</returns>
    public static string GetDriveLetter(string path) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The path argument was null or whitespace.");
        }

        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("The path '{0}' was not a rooted path and GetDriveLetter does not support relative paths.",
                path)
            );
        }

        if (path.StartsWith(@"\\")) {
            throw new ArgumentException("A UNC path was passed to GetDriveLetter");
        }

        return Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path).Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), "");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"])` causes a *The type initializer for 'System.Management.ManagementPath' threw an exception*, do you know if this code works on Windows7 or could it be Group Policy?

Comment: @JeremyThompson The InnerException for this exception (which I am also getting) is [System.Threading.ThreadAbortException] {"Exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' was thrown."}. I do not know the cause of this yet, but am still looking for a solution. I'm running Win7 x64.

Comment: +1; I ended using this code with some small changes: 1. Made the class and methods static; 2. mo["DriveType"] can be casted directly to uint and then to System.IO.DriveType. This way I don't have to deal with those magic numbers. 3. Put mo in an using statement. [mo = null doesn't really help the GC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/574659/2504607)

Comment: This solution does not appear to resolve drives mapped using `subst` (for which the System.IO.DriveType is `Fixed`)

Answer (score 36):

I can't remember where I found this, but it works **without** p/invoke. It's what *rerun* posted before.

you need to reference *System.Management.dll*:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
```

code:

```
public void FindUNCPaths()
{
   DriveInfo[] dis = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
   foreach( DriveInfo di in dis )
   {
      if(di.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
      {
         DirectoryInfo dir = di.RootDirectory;
         // "x:"
         MessageBox.Show( GetUNCPath( dir.FullName.Substring( 0, 2 ) ) );
      }
   }
}

public string GetUNCPath(string path)
{
   if(path.StartsWith(@"\\")) 
   {
      return path;
   }

   ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();
   mo.Path = new ManagementPath( String.Format( "Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", path ) );

   // DriveType 4 = Network Drive
   if(Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]) == 4 )
   {
      return Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]);
   }
   else 
   {
      return path;
   }
}
```

**Update:**
Explicitly running **as administrator** will not show mapped drives. Here is an explanation of this behaviour:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11268410/448100
(in short: administrator has a different user context, so no access to mapped drives of normal user)

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs and seems to be the simplest solution. I'm surprised I haven't seen this anywhere else.

Comment: Fails on Windows 8 when `path = "C:\\"` with a `ManagementException` not found.

Comment: @Loathing Did you find a solution for the `ManagementException`? I'm also hitting this error. Thanks.

Comment: @kurifodo The solution is to trim off the backslashes and just use `C:`. I'll post the code I actually use below in a new answer.

Comment: @ibram This is not working in windows 10 when the program is running as admin. Might have to pinvoke if you want to find info when program is running as admin and work across different platforms.

Comment: @DavidBentley thank you for your feedback. This is also not working in windows 7. I added that to my answer. (DriveInfo.GetDrives() returns only fixed drives as admin)

Answer (score 24):

I've written a method for this. It returns a UNC path if it is a mapped drive, otherwise it returns the path unchanged.

```
public static string UNCPath(string path)
{
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Network\\" + path[0]))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            path = key.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString() + path.Remove(0, 2).ToString();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

**EDIT**

You now can use the Method even with already UNC paths. The above version of the method throws an exception if given a UNC path.

```
public static string UNCPath(string path)
{
    if (!path.StartsWith(@"\\"))
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Network\\" + path[0]))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                return key.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString() + path.Remove(0, 2).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: I found this to work really well. Neat, short and simple.

Comment: Is there an other path in the Registry to find this values? Because i found all but one (please see screenshot): [link](http://imgur.com/AxA9FJN)

Comment: It looks as simplest solution, that works for earlier .Net framework (like 2.0) where no "System.Management" namespace yet and it works with no additional libraries. It needs only namespace used "Microsoft.Win32".

Comment: This solution is not valid for Windows 10

Comment: Most elegant solution - thanks.  No problem on Win 10

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use the "Network" key From the "Current User" Hive, In the Registry.
The Mapped Drives Are Listed There With Their Shared Path On Server.

If there is no mapped drive in the system, so there is no "Network" Key In The "Current User" Hive.

Now, I'm using this way, no external dll nor anything else.

Comment: Not valid for Windows 10

Comment: This looks like the cleanest way to do it, except it's not accurate.  I'm looking at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network and it only shows one of my 15 mapped network drives.  Don't trust this method.

Answer (score 5):

[QueryDosDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365461(VS.85).aspx) translates a drive letter into the path that it expands to.

Note that this will translate ALL drive letters, not just those that are mapped to network connections.  You need to already know which are network paths, or to parse the output to see which are network.

Here's the VB signature

```
Declare Function QueryDosDevice Lib "kernel32" Alias "QueryDosDeviceA" (
       ByVal lpDeviceName    As String, 
       ByVal lpTargetPath As String, 
       ByVal ucchMax As Integer) As Integer
```

And the C# one

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, IntPtr lpTargetPath, uint ucchMax);
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, also this look like it will not give the folder, mapped driver are to a server and a folder...

Comment: If you mean you want to know that path as it appears to the server, then you will need to ask the server.  That information isn't available to the client.

Comment: If the drive is mapped on the machine the code is running on then it should work.

Comment: You will get back \\server\share on the machine that the drive is mapped on.  The server may have share aliased to c:\foo\bar\whatever, If you want that then you have to ask the server.

Answer (score 5):

You can use WMI to interrogate the Win32_LogicalDrive collection on your machine.  [Here is an example of how to do it with scripting](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/27/how-can-i-determine-which-drives-are-mapped-to-network-shares.aspx).  Changing this over to C# is pretty well explained in other places.

Slightly modified VB.NET code from the article:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim strComputer = "."

        Dim objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

        Dim colDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4")

        For Each objDrive In colDrives
            Debug.WriteLine("Drive letter: " & objDrive.DeviceID)
            Debug.WriteLine("Network path: " & objDrive.ProviderName)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Dead simple way of getting the network share of each mapped drive without using any special libraries. This works straight out of the box in a VS Express 2012 for Desktop Windows Form application.

Comment: While this does work it fails at least on Windows 10 on network drives. If you remove the 'DriveType = 4' you will get a list of all local drives but no mapped network drives.

Answer (score 5):

I could not replicate [ibram's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5496595/1751715) or [Vermis'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795595/1751715) answer due to the problem I mentioned in a comment under Vermis' answer, about a type initializer exception.

Instead, I discovered I could query for all the drives currently on the computer and then loop through them, like so:

```
using System.IO; //For DirectoryNotFound exception.
using System.Management;


/// <summary>
/// Given a local mapped drive letter, determine if it is a network drive. If so, return the server share.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mappedDrive"></param>
/// <returns>The server path that the drive maps to ~ "////XXXXXX//ZZZZ"</returns>
private string CheckUNCPath(string mappedDrive)
{
    //Query to return all the local computer's drives.
    //See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146.aspx, or search "WMI Queries"
    SelectQuery selectWMIQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_LogicalDisk");
    ManagementObjectSearcher driveSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectWMIQuery);

    //Soem variables to be used inside and out of the foreach.
    ManagementPath path = null;
    ManagementObject networkDrive = null;
    bool found = false;
    string serverName = null;

    //Check each disk, determine if it is a network drive, and then return the real server path.
    foreach (ManagementObject disk in driveSearcher.Get())
    {
        path = disk.Path;

        if (path.ToString().Contains(mappedDrive))
        {
            networkDrive = new ManagementObject(path);

            if (Convert.ToUInt32(networkDrive["DriveType"]) == 4)
            {
                serverName = Convert.ToString(networkDrive["ProviderName"]);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("The drive " + mappedDrive + " was found, but is not a network drive. Were your network drives mapped correctly?");
            }
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("The drive " + mappedDrive + " was not found. Were your network drives mapped correctly?");
    }
    else
    {
        return serverName;
    }
}
```

This works for x64 Windows 7, for .NET 4. It should be usable in case you're getting that exception that was mentioned above.

I did this using the stuff given from MSDN and bits from [ibram's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5496595/1751715) or [Vermis'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795595/1751715) answers, though it was a bit difficult to find specific examples on the MSDN. Resources used:

[MSDN : Win32_LogicalDisk Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[MSDN : System.Management namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx)

[MSDN : WMI Queries example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Management;
class Query_SelectQuery
{
    public static int Main(string[] args) 
    {
        SelectQuery selectQuery = new 
            SelectQuery("Win32_LogicalDisk");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery);

        foreach (ManagementObject disk in searcher.Get()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disk.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to ibram's answer with a few modifications:

```
public static String GetUNCPath(String path) {
    path = path.TrimEnd('\\', '/') + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    String root = d.Root.FullName.TrimEnd('\\');

    if (!root.StartsWith(@"\\")) {
        ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();
        mo.Path = new ManagementPath(String.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", root));

        // DriveType 4 = Network Drive
        if (Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]) == 4)
            root = Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]);
        else
            root = @"\\" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + "\\" + root.TrimEnd(':') + "$\\";
    }

    return Recombine(root, d);
}

private static String Recombine(String root, DirectoryInfo d) {
    Stack s = new Stack();
    while (d.Parent != null) {
        s.Push(d.Name);
        d = d.Parent;
    }

    while (s.Count > 0) {
        root = Path.Combine(root, (String) s.Pop());
    }
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems it's need a P/Invoke: [Converting a mapped drive letter to a network path using C#](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/22)

This guy built a managed class to deal with it: [C# Map Network Drive (API)](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357/)

Comment: Looks like this allows you to map or un-map drives via code, I don't see anything on obtaining a path from a mapped path.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use WMI Win32_LogicalDisk to get all the information you need.  use the ProviderName from the class to get the UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Windows cares, what's needed is a call to `WNetGetConnection`. I don't know of a front-end for that in .NET, so you may have to call it via P/Invoke (fortunately, it has only one parameter, the P/Invoke code isn't too awful).

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e43cc927-4bcc-42d7-9630-f5fdfdb4a1fa/get-absolute-path-of-drive-mapped-to-local-folder?forum=netfxnetcom) describe how to get the absolute path of a drive which is mapped to a local folder?

> For example, I have a "c:\test" folder and an "x:" drive which is
>   mapped to c:\test.
>
> I'm looking for a function which will return "c:\test" when I pass in
>   "x:"

The answer is:

> SUBST uses DefineDosDevice (XP and later) to create the drive/path
>   mapping.  You can use the QueryDosDevice to get the path of a SUBSTed
>   drive:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]

private    static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

static String GetPhysicalPath(String path)

{

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))

    {

        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

    }

    // Get the drive letter

    string pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(path);

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathRoot))

    {

        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

    }

    string lpDeviceName = pathRoot.Replace("\\", "");



    const String substPrefix = @"\??\";

    StringBuilder lpTargetPath = new StringBuilder(260);



    if (0 != QueryDosDevice(lpDeviceName, lpTargetPath, lpTargetPath.Capacity))

    {

        string result;



        // If drive is substed, the result will be in the format of "\??\C:\RealPath\".

        if (lpTargetPath..ToString().StartsWith(substPrefix))

        {

            // Strip the \??\ prefix.

            string root = lpTargetPath.ToString().Remove(0, substPrefix.Length);



            result = Path.Combine(root, path.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(path), ""));

        }

        else

        {

            // TODO: deal with other types of mappings.

            // if not SUBSTed, just assume it's not mapped.

            result = path;

        }

        return result;

    }

    else

    {

        // TODO: error reporting

        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't care if it is local or remote

```
    private string uncpath_check(string path)
    {
        string rval = path;
        string driveprefix = path.Substring(0, 2);
        string unc;

        if (driveprefix != "\\")
        {
            ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();
            try
            {
                mo.Path = new ManagementPath(String.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", driveprefix));
                unc = (string)mo["ProviderName"];
                rval = path.Replace(driveprefix, unc);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        if (rval == null)
        { rval = path; }

        return rval;
    }
```