# PathFileExists returns false when executing application through RemoteApp

Tags: c++, path, unc, remoteapp

My executable built in *C++/WinAPI* will check for a file placed in the same folder and I use `PathFileExists` for that. When I run it on a normal computer it finds the file but when I publish the executable on **RemoteApp** and I run it from **Web Access** the file is not found. What would I be missing?

```
// This is the file I want to find (located in the same directory as the EXE)
wstring myfile = L"myfile.conf";
BOOL abspath = FALSE;

// Trying to get the absolute path first
DWORD nBufferLength = MAX_PATH;
wchar_t szCurrentDirectory[MAX_PATH + 1];
if (GetCurrentDirectory(nBufferLength, szCurrentDirectory) == 0) {
    szCurrentDirectory[MAX_PATH + 1] = '\0';
} else {
    abspath = true;
}

if (abspath) {
    // Create the absolute path to the file
    myfile = L'\\' + myfile;
    myfile = szCurrentDirectory + myfile ;
    MessageBox(hWnd, ConvertToUNC(myfile).c_str(), L"Absolute Path", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
} else {
    // Get the UNC path
    myfile = ConvertToUNC(myfile);
    MessageBox(hWnd, myfile.c_str(), L"UNC Path", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

//  Try to find file
int retval = PathFileExists(myfile.c_str());

if (retval == 1) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // File not found
}
```

The `ConvertToUNC` function is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233501/how-can-i-get-a-unc-path-for-a-file-that-is-accessed-through-a-network-drive).
What I see is that, although the executable lies somewhere else, the absolute path is considered to be `C:\Windows`. I really don't know what is causing this. The server is Windows 2012 R2 and, like I said, applications are run through RemoteApp Web Access. The returned UNC path is just the name of the file (no volume or folder)

Comment: "*What would I be missing?*" -- What you're missing is a call to `GetLastError` to see why `PathFileExists" returns FALSE.

Comment: Access rights? Will RemoteApps have permission to read the directory?