# How do I retrieve the network path of the source executable using C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to programmatically retrieve the network path where the C++ executable is stored. For clarity, when I say network path, I mean the path retrieved in Windows manually by: 'right clicking the folder', 'choosing properties', and 'selecting the sharing tab'. An example of this path can be [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGm72.jpg).

Does anyone know how to adapt my below code to retrieve the network path (as specified above) rather than the local path?

Here is minimal reproducing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

using namespace std;

std::wstring GetExecutableDirectory()
{
    // Get the full path to the executable file
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    // Remove the file name from the path
    PathRemoveFileSpec(buffer);

    return std::wstring(buffer);
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring localPath = GetExecutableDirectory();
    
    // SOME CODE  IN HERE TO GET THE NETWORK-SHARE PATH   
    //....

    wcout << L"Local path: " << localPath << endl;
    wcout << L"Network-share path: ";   

    return 0;
}
```

I use Visual Studio 2022 as my coding environment, and my OS is Windows 11. For context, I am new to this language and still learning.

I've tried several things to troubleshoot (but had no luck), including:

- trying the WNetGetUniversalName function, as implemented by [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233501/how-can-i-get-a-unc-path-for-a-file-that-is-accessed-through-a-network-drive).
  I also asked a previous question related to this that can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75546373/how-do-i-convert-local-path-to-unc-in-c-with-wnetgetuniversalname-function-ge/75549108?noredirect=1#comment133298966_75549108)
- checking the local path exists (it does, and is found by the sample code)
- checking the sharing permissions within the local path folder (they are set to share with everyone)
- running the C++ code directly from the executable (instead of the VS2022 debugger)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no one-stop function for this. You'll have to calculate it from `NetShareEnum` and looking for matching paths.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Raymond. Please let me know if you or anyone else has minimal reproducible code to help implement the function with NetShareEnum.

Comment: You may be waiting a long time. This site is not about "Please give me prewritten code to solve my problem."