# How to get a fully qualified UNC path?

Tags: c#, path, fileinfo

This might be simple and I'm just overlooking something.

The `FileInfo.FileName` of a file lying on a network share returns something like this:

```
H:\Directory1\Dir2\...
```

What I need, though:

```
\\server\share\Directory1\Dir2\...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the FullName Property work for you?

Comment: @Mathew I just tried using that on my work machine which has a mapped drive, and no it does not work.

Comment: @MUG4N Thank you for the clarification. http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/22 taken from the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2067100/1329396