# Given a path, how can i find out its host?

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming

How can I implement this function:

```
GetHost("C:\MyFolder"); //Local
GetHost("D:\MyFolder"); //Local
GetHost("\\FileServer1\MyFolder"); //FileServer1
GetHost("Y:\MyFolder"); //FileServer1
GetHost("\\LocalSharedFolder\MyOtherFolder"); //Local
GetHost("\\SpecialSharedFolder\YetAnotherFolder"); //FileServer2
```

**Edit1:**
So far i've tried juggling [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), [DriveInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), [ManagementClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: I believe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404433/how-to-get-a-fully-qualified-unc-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetDriveType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can tell me if the disk is local or not in case of "Y://". [WNetGetConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can point me the network path for it, on the case of `\\LocaSharedFolder`, where I can extract its host name...