# Get Current Executable Directory On Map Drive

Tags: c#, windows

I have a map drive at location *Z:\* which is mapped to *\\server1\shared*
Now my executable located at *\\server1\shared\exe\myExec.exe*

I have tried

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

All of them return `"\\server1\shared\exe"`

Is there a way I can get a result to be `"Z:\exe\"` ?

Comment: Not really... Are you looking for finding all mappings of network path to a letter (should be several existing duplicates for that).

Comment: I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with these 2 functions.

`UNC2LocalPath` takes UNC Path and return local path. It iterates thru all drives that being map at the local machine. If found a match, it replace server name with the drive letter.

**Required reference**: *System.Management.dll*

```
using System.Management;

public static String UNC2LocalPath(String input)
{
    DriveInfo[] dis = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo di in dis)
    {
        if (di.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = di.RootDirectory;
            var unc = GetUNCPath(dir.FullName.Substring(0, 2));
            if (input.StartsWith(unc_path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return input.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(unc) + "\\", dir.FullName);
            }
        }                
    }
    return null;
}

public static string GetUNCPath(string path)
{
    if (path.StartsWith(@"\\"))
        return path;

    ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();
    mo.Path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", path));

    //DriveType 4 = Network Drive
    if (Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]) == 4)
        return Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]);
    else return path;
}
```

The function `GetUNCPath` is taken from ibram's answer @ [How do I determine a mapped drive's actual path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067075/how-do-i-determine-a-mapped-drives-actual-path)