# How to convert a local file path in PC to a Network Relative or UNC path?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
String machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
String filePath = @"E:\folder1\folder2\file1";
int a = filePath.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
filePath = filePath.Substring(filePath.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) +1);
String networdPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(string.Concat(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), machineName, filePath);
Console.WriteLine(networdPath);
```

I wrote the above code using `String.Concat` and `Path.Combine` to get network path. But it is just a workaround and not a concrete solution and may fail.
Is there a concrete solution for getting a network path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067075/how-do-i-determine-a-mapped-drives-actual-path

Answer (score 4):

You are assuming that your `E:\folder1` local path is shared as `\\mypc\folder1`, which in general is not true, so I doubt a general method that does what you want to do exists.

You are on the right path in implementing what you are trying to achieve. You can get more help from `System.IO.Path`; see `Path.GetPathRoot` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot(v=vs.110).aspx) for returned values according to different kind of path in input

```
string GetNetworkPath(string path)
{
    string root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);

    // validate input, in your case you are expecting a path starting with a root of type "E:\"
    // see Path.GetPathRoot on MSDN for returned values
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(root) || !root.Contains(":"))
    {
        // handle invalid input the way you prefer
        // I would throw!
        throw new ApplicationException("be gentle, pass to this function the expected kind of path!");
    }
    path = path.Remove(0, root.Length);
    return Path.Combine(@"\\myPc", path);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but our solution will only work for Microsoft windows.The pattern for mac OS network path might be different than that of windows and Our solution won't work there. So is there a concrete solution provided by microsoft which will work on all possible OS.