# C# Win Form - Allow to save file only on LOCAL PC

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, backup-sqldatabase

### Brief

I am trying to backup SQL Database through my software. At runtime the software asks the user where does he want the backup to be stored.

### Requirement

Now, my requirement is that the user can only create backup on the PC itself or on any pendrive attached to it but not on network PC.

### Solution that i came up with

Here is the code i am using:-

```
SaveFileDialog obj = new SaveFileDialog();
obj.DefaultExt = ".bak";
obj.FileName = FileName;
obj.ShowDialog();
if (obj.FileName != null && obj.FileName != "" && obj.FileName.StartsWith("\\\\") == false)
{
     //Save File Work
}
```

### Question

Now, i want to ask you guys is that will this code `obj.FileName.StartsWith("\\\\") == false` be sufficient to block the user from saving on network drives or is there any other method i should use to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I can likely work around this limitation using `pushd` to map a network drive prior. https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-the-pushd-popd-commands-for-quick-network-drive-mapping-in-windows-7/

Comment: you can check path is network path or not and using `new Uri(mypath).IsUnc` and then block user based on that

Comment: @PranayRana yes it is perfect. can you write it as an answer

Comment: @Agent_Spock - added

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067075/how-do-i-determine-a-mapped-drives-actual-path may be of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check path is network path or not and using `new Uri(mypath).IsUnc` and then block user based on that

so code will be like

```
if (new Uri(path).IsUnc || IsNetworkPath(path))
{
  //show message not allowed
  return;
}

//for checking path is network or not 
private bool IsNetworkPath(path) 
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
    DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(file.Directory.Root.FullName);
    return dive.DrivType == DrivType .Network;    
}
```