# Using C#, how can I access the original local path of a remote network drive? (not the UNC path)

Tags: c#, windows, path

I need to access the remote file structure for use in SQL backups.

For example, the remote server named "remote" has the path "C:\backup folder", which is enabled as a remote drive.

I can map to that remote drive as "Z:\backup folder" on my machine.

I can use the various answers in [How do I determine a mapped drive's actual path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067075/how-do-i-determine-a-mapped-drives-actual-path) to determine the UNC path is "\\remote\backup folder". This doesn't work for the SQL backup system, since it is all handled on the remote server.

**How can I access the original path on the remote server, "C:\backup folder"?**

Comment: Can you define the UNC configuration in terms of `\\<server>\c$\` ?

Comment: Maybe via https://superuser.com/questions/465038/finding-the-physical-local-path-associated-with-a-share-unc-folder ?

Comment: Which probably means you can do that in C# via something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Win32_Share Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-share),  [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572), [System.Management Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), and [ManagementObjectSearcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)