# Cleartext Password with XMLSerialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, asmx

I'm communicating with a Third-Party Web Service using XML. Everything is working fine, except that our Security scanner is reporting a few [CWE-216](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/316.html) flaws.

The password is indeed stored in memory within a `LoginDetails` class similar to below (Simplified for examples sake)

```
[Serializable()]
public class LoginDetails
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The third-party requires the password to be sent in clear-text. So unfortunately I have no choice in the matter here. What I want to do is ensure that the field is stored securely and/or removed from memory as soon as possible when it has been used.

In terms of remediation I have attempted the use of both `SecureString` -for obvious reasons- and using `StringBuilder` as this negates the immutability. I have also tried to implement `IDisposable` on the `LoginDetails` class. This consisted of setting the two properties to null. I was then lead to various discussions ([particularly this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574019/setting-an-object-to-null-vs-dispose)) stating that it's not really of much benefit.

The problem is, when changing the `Password` fields type to `SecureString` or `StringBuilder` - They aren't serialized correctly - and therefore the request fails at the third-party. Is there any way I can override the `XMLSerializer` to process these types differently - so they are stored somewhat more securely in memory on our side, but transmitted in clear-text to the third-party - Or is the whole attempt pointless on the basis that these attempts at security won't be implemented on both sides?

Alternatively is there anything I have completely overlooked?

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by they aren't serialised correctly?

Comment: Let me rephrase that bit. I'm assuming they are serialized "correctly" as according to their types. SecureString isn't serializable (understandable), whereas StringBuilder serializes as <StringBuilder><Capacity>xx</Capacity><Length>xx</Length></StringBuilder>. What I need is something that holds secure (or more secure than what I have now) until the I use XMLSerializer - at which point the cleartext value of the Password property is transmitted to the Third-Party.

Comment: Scratch that just remmeber StringBuilder is Non-Inherit.

Comment: I guess you could write a wrapper class for the StringBuilder with a property bound to .ToString() just through ideas around, been a while since I dealt with this, don't remember how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this I created a custom type named `SerializableSecureString` implementing both `IXmlSerializable` and `IDisposable`.

Hope the following helps someone out in the future!

**Implementation**

The type contains a private `SecureString` member variable, and a private `string` property which is used for the serialization.

```
private readonly SecureString Content = new SecureString();
private string Value { }
```

The `get` for the private string property unwraps the private member variable as follows...

```
get
{
    IntPtr bstr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(Content);
    string copiedText = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(bstr);
    Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(bstr);

    return copiedText;
}
```

There are two constructors. An empty constructor used solely by .Net for Serialization...

```
public SerializableSecureString()
{
}
```

...and another for actual construction of the type. It takes a cleartext string and packages it up into the SecureString variable like so...

```
public SerializableSecureString(string clearText)
{
    if (clearText != null)
    {
        foreach (char t in clearText)
            Content.AppendChar(t);
    }
}
```

The serialization happens in the implementation of `IXmlSerializable` in the `WriteXml` function. It uses `WriteString` to write out the value of the private string property (Value)...

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteString(Value);
}
```

To dispose the SecureString value, I implemented the `Dispose` method within the `IDisposable` pattern and called `Content.Dispose()`

**Usage**

I can create an instance of the `LoginDetails` class (as quoted in the question) as follows...

```
LoginDetails loginDetails = new LoginDetails
{
    Login = "MyUsername",
    Password = new SerializableSecureString(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyPassword"])
};
```

The password is stored in an encrypted section of the web.config file - hence the use of `WebConfigurationManager`.

After use, the data can be disposed within a `finally` block like the following

```
finally
{
    LoginDetails.Password.Dispose();
}
```