# HttpClient is not getting null outside using block

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, http

i have a class in which there is a method wich returns http client like below.

```
private HttpClient client;
private HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        if (this.client == null)
        {
            this.client = new HttpClient
            {
                 BaseAddress = new Uri("api")
            };   
            this.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
            return this.client;
    }
```

i am using this GetClient method in other methods like

```
                using (var client = this.GetClient())
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync($"/abc").ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
```

this client is not getting null outside the using block.next time when this method hits then client is not null.whats the problem?

Comment: Disposing doesn't mean that the object which will be disposed is getting null. It just  frees the used ressources on the object.

Comment: Note that `using (var client ...)` creates a different `client`variable than the one declared at class scope. The `client` variable from the using declaration is not even defined outside the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect it to be null? Disposing an object doesn't set references to it to null, it simply calls `Dispose()`, rendering the instance to an unusable state (when properly implemented).

See also [Setting an object to null vs Dispose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574019/setting-an-object-to-null-vs-dispose).

Also, don't dispose your HttpClient, read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: but if i use  using (var client =new httpclient()) then it gives null outside scope, why so?

Comment: and i do not have frequent calls to this method, no performance issues thats why disposing it.