# MemoryStream.Close() or MemoryStream.Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Which one do I call?

Is it necessary to call both?

Will the other throw an exception if I have already called one of them?

Comment: Dispose() would handle everything

Comment: Wrap your usage in using and don't worry about it.

using (var s = new MemoryStream())
{   
}

See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968289/memorystream-in-using-statement-do-i-need-to-call-close

Comment: Call neither. The `Close()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.close?view=net-7.0#system-io-stream-close) says to make sure the stream is properly disposed instead of calling it, and the `MemoryStream` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-7.0#remarks) clearly says that it is not necessary to call `Dispose()` as it doesn't have any resources to dispose. So, after you're done with a `MemoryStream`, just leave it like any other managed type and GC will do the rest.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

`Close()` and `Dispose()`, when called on a `MemoryStream`, only serve to do two things:

- Mark the object disposed so that future accidental usage of the object will throw an exception.
- Possibly<sup>1</sup> release references to managed objects, which can make the GC's job a bit easier depending on the GC implementation.  (On today's GC algorithms it makes no real difference, so this is a point for an academic discussion and has no significant real-world impact.)

`MemoryStream` does not have any unmanaged resources to dispose, so you don't technically have to dispose of it.  The effect of not disposing a `MemoryStream` is roughly the same thing as dropping a reference to a `byte[]` -- the GC will clean both up the same way.

> Which one do I call?  Is it necessary to call both?

The `Dispose()` method of streams [delegate directly to the `Close()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx)<sup>2</sup>, so both do exactly the same thing.

> Will the other throw an exception if I have already called one of them?

The [documentation for `IDisposable.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) specifically states it is safe to call `Dispose()` multiple times, on any object<sup>3</sup>.  (If that is not true for a particular class then that class implements the `IDisposable` interface in a way that violates its contract, and this would be a bug.)

All that to say: it really doesn't make a huge difference whether you dispose a `MemoryStream` or not.  The only real reason it has `Close`/`Dispose` methods is because it inherits from `Stream`, which requires those methods as part of its contract to support streams that *do* have unmanaged resources (such as file or socket descriptors).

---

<sup>1</sup> [Mono's implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/137a5c40cfecff099f3b5e97c425663ed2e8505d/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/MemoryStream.cs#L220) does not release the `byte[]` reference.  I don't know if the Microsoft implementation does.

<sup>2</sup> *"This method calls Close, which then calls Stream.Dispose(Boolean)."*

<sup>3</sup> *"If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one."*

Comment: Note that the part about disposing the `MemoryStream` making the GC's job easier only applies if for some reason you held a reference to the disposed stream object.

Comment: @EdwardBrey True.  It depends on the GC implementation.  All popular CLR implementations today use some variant of mark-and-sweep GC, so it's really an academic discussion -- today's GCs won't show any difference.

Comment: In reference to your footnote `1`, according to the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) `.Dispose()` does not release the internal `byte[]` either. The only resource it sets `null` is `_lastReadTask` which is only used in the method `Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[], int, int, CancellationToken)`. Besides setting that one variable null all it does is set `_isOpen`, `_writable`, and `_expandable` to `false`.

Answer (score 35):

None of the above. You needn't call either `Close` or `Dispose`.

`MemoryStream` doesn't hold any unmanaged resources, so the only resource to be reclaimed is memory. The memory will be reclaimed during garbage collection with the rest of the `MemoryStream` object when your code no longer references the `MemoryStream`.

If you have a long-lived reference to the `MemoryStream`, you can set that reference to null to allow the `MemoryStream` to be garbage collected. `Close` and `Dispose` free neither the steam buffer nor the `MemoryStream` object proper.

Since neither `Stream` nor `MemoryStream` have a finalizer, there is no need to call `Close` or `Dispose` to cause `GC.SuppressFinalize` to be called to optimize garbage collection. There is no finalizer to suppress.

The docs for [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream) put it this way:

> This type implements the `IDisposable` interface, but does not actually have any resources to dispose. This means that disposing it by directly calling `Dispose()` or by using a language construct such as `using` (in C#) or `Using` (in Visual Basic) is not necessary.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `using` block for this. It will automatically call `Dispose` when it goes outside of its scope.

Example:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Do something with ms..
}
// ms is disposed here
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 8):

Use `using` block so that your object is disposed if its implements `IDisposable` interface

Answer (score 6):

the following code is Stream.Dispose from reflector as you can see, you don't need to close if you dispose (which is implicit when using using)

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Which one do I call?

Any of them.

> Is it necessary to call both?

No, either one is sufficient.

> Will the other throw an exception if I have already called one of them?

No, disposable pattern declares that subsequent calls to Dispose don't cause negative effects.

Comment: Just went through this on a live application. Close and Dispose do act differently in CLR 4.5. Dispose should be sufficient, but you can call Close and then Dispose if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

Calling Close() will internally call Dispose() to release the resources.

See this link for more information:
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx)

Comment: I think you meant that calling `Dispose()` will internally call `Close()` but not other way.

Answer (score 2):

Calling only `Dispose()` will do the trick =)

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 3.5 (haven't checked other versions), methods are called in the following order when disposing a MemoryStream:

1. Stream.Dispose()

   - simply calls Close
2. Stream.Close()

   - calls Dispose(true), then GC.SuppressFinalize(this)
3. MemoryStream.Dispose(true)

   - sets _isOpen , _writable, and _expandable flags to false
4. Stream.Dispose(true)

   - closes async event if active

Answer (score 1):

As a first solution, it's recommended to use using statements wherever possible. This is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

> When the lifetime of an IDisposable object is limited to a single method, you should declare and instantiate it in the using statement. **The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called.** Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

Coming to the question now, as others suggested in most .NET framework classes, there is no difference between Close() and Dispose() and it doesn't matter which of the two methods you call. You should call one but not both. However, **there are exceptions**.

> There are exceptions; for example, System.Windows.Forms.Form and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection have different behavior for Close() and Dispose().

For complete details, you can check here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kimhamil/2008/03/15/the-often-non-difference-between-close-and-dispose/