# MemoryStream in Using Statement - Do I need to call close()

Tags: c#, using, memorystream, using-statement

When using a memory stream in a using statement do I need to call close? For instance is ms.Close() needed here?

```
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray)) 
    {  
      // stuff 

      ms.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/234257/490018

Comment: possible dub: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911408/does-stream-dispose-always-call-stream-close-and-stream-flush

Answer (score 71, accepted):

No, it's not.

`using` ensures that [`Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422) will be called, which in turn calls the `Close()` method.

You can assume that all kinds of Streams are getting closed by the `using` statement.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx):

> When you use an object that accesses unmanaged resources, such as a StreamWriter, a good practice is to create the instance with a using statement. **The using statement automatically closes the stream and calls Dispose on the object when the code that is using it has completed**.

Comment: I realize this is old, but I would just like to add that using a `.Close()` in addition to the `using` will also cause code analysis warning "CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times". For more information, read the "Cause" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CA2202);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0)

Comment: Is it not the other way around. That `.Close()` will call `.Dispose()`? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Dispose() calls Close() which calls Dispose(boolean).

Answer (score 8):

> When using a memory stream in a using statement do I need to call close?

No, you don't need. It will be called by the `.Dispose()` method which is automatically called:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray)) 
{  
    // stuff 
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually `Dispose()` calls `Close()` which in turn calls `Dispose(true)`.