# Displaying live images

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I have a function that returns an array of bytes containing the data of a bmp img live from a camera (including header).
I write that array in to a MemoryStream object.
That object, I pass to a Image object constructor, which will be passed to a PictureBox.

tl;dr:

```
byte[] AoB = GetImage();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(AoB, 0, AoB.Length);
pictureBoxImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
ms.Dispose();
```

All of this is done in a timer with a delay of 200 ms (5fps).
It works fine for about a minute or 2 until OutOfMemory exception.
For some reason, even though I dispose of the memory used, it keeps generating new one.
I've also tried to declare ms as global and flush it every time, still no go.
How can I stream the images while using the same memory space?

Comment: How big are the byte arrays?

Comment: Your issue could be that your version of `Dispose` does not release `byte[]`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4274769/27678

Answer (score 2):

Try disposing the Image objects when you're done with them as well:

```
byte[] AoB = GetImage();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    ms.Write(AoB, 0, AoB.Length);
    Image old = pictureBoxImage.Image;
    pictureBoxImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    if (old != null) {
        old.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should dispose the old images when you are done with them ([as adv12 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21437614/80274)), however you are also creating two `byte[]`s in memory. The first one is the one you get from `GetImage()` the second one is the one stored inside the `MemoryStream` and that one could be larger than your source array due to its growing algorithms.

Instead use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `MemoryStream` constructor to allow you to pass the `byte[]` directly in and the `MemoryStream` will reuse that single array for its internal store, reducing the memory requirement.

```
byte[] AoB = GetImage();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(AoB)) {
    Image old = pictureBoxImage.Image;
    pictureBoxImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    old.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... It managed to slow it down a bit but it still builds up the memory and crashes. I guess I'll have to use a C++ dll or unsafe snippet... Unless you have any other ideas?

Comment: @SharonJDDorot, if the above didn't fix your leak, I would guess the problem is in the GetImage method.  Have you tried calling GetImage() repeatedly without any of the other code?

Comment: The GetImage() function doesn't really exist, it's listed to cover un-related code that will result in the image array. What it does is read the bytes from the sensor, re-arrange them in order for colored image and add the BMP header. Yes, I have done it in a loop and dumped it to a file instead of MemoryStream and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your timer's `AutoReset=false` and manually starting it over at the end of the last call.

```
myTimer.AutoReset = false;
```

Start after image assignment.

```
byte[] AoB = GetImage();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(AoB, 0, AoB.Length);
pictureBoxImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
ms.Dispose();
myTimer.Start().
```

The timer has the potential to get ahead of the retrieval of the images.

Comment: Multiple threads?  Do we know what sort of timer she's using?  If it's a Windows Forms timer, it should only call back on the GUI thread...