# C# Memory Managment

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am Eager to know how to do memory management in c# application.

My application is not releasing memory even I dispose objects and make it nullify.
For testing purpose, I have created sample application as described below.

An application has two buttons 
1) Consume Memory
2) Release Memory

By clicking on Consume Memory I am going to create and add 500 Memory Stream objects into List.

By clicking on Release Memory I am going to dispose all Memory Stream object and nullify that List too. and Collect garbage collection.

But when I start an application at that time my task manager will show me 8.6 MB Memory usage. When I press Consume Memory at that time task manager will show me 679.6 MB Memory Usage. When I Press Release Memory at that time task manager will show 680.0 MB Memory usage.

How can I forcefully release memory?

> Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<System.IO.MemoryStream> MemoryStreamCollection = new List<System.IO.MemoryStream>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ConsumeMemory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            MemoryStreamCollection.Add(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\TestPDF.pdf")));
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }

    private void ReleaseMemory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream in MemoryStreamCollection)
        {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }

        MemoryStreamCollection = null;

        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
}
```

> Screenshot when an application starts

[image]

> Screenshot after consume memory button click.

[image]

> Screenshot after release memory button click.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to hold onto all the objects and once, then release them in one go? If not, you could try seeing how it behaves if you use `using` blocks to create them so they're automatically released when they're no longer needed.

Comment: Have you tried calling GC.Collect() without the optional parameters?

Comment: By adding `MemoryStreamCollection.Clear();` before `MemoryStreamCollection = null;` the memory leak will no longer occur. I have successfully tested it with your sample code. But I have no clue why this List does not get collected when you forcibly call GC. Even with `WaitForPendingFinalizers`, it does not get collected.

Comment: Extending @bommelding comment, `MemoryStream.Dispose()` or `MemoryStream.Close()` don't really need to be called. They lead to the same mathod and they don't have any unmanaged resources. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274590/memorystream-close-or-memorystream-dispose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a third button called `GarbageCollect` and modify your code as follows, it will work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication9
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<System.IO.MemoryStream> MemoryStreamCollection = new List<System.IO.MemoryStream>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ConsumeMemory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                MemoryStreamCollection.Add(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\bpmn.png")));
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        private void ReleaseMemory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream in MemoryStreamCollection)
            {
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }

            MemoryStreamCollection = null;

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        private void GarbageCollect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is that in your code, you are calling `GC.Collect` while the temporary variables of the `foreach` loop still are on the stack:

```
private void ReleaseMemory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream in MemoryStreamCollection)
    {
        memoryStream.Dispose();
    }

    MemoryStreamCollection = null;

    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

By moving `GC.Collect` out of the function scope, the `List` and its iterator will no longer be on the local stack and GC can successfully do its job.

This is the situation in your sample code before the `MessageBox.Show("Done")` line in the `ReleaseMemory_Click()` method, as shown in a memory profiler:

[image: screen shot]

As you can see, the List and one MemoryStream is held by the stack frame of the `ReleaseMemory_Click()` method.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankM It works but in any c# application which things I need to take care to avoid this kind of glitch.

Comment: My advice: test, test, test... Especially with large data sets. And if you encounter any memory leak, use the memory profiler in Visual Studio or a 3rd party tool for diagnosing the root cause of the leak. Regarding types with `IDisposable` interface, try to use the `using (...)` pattern whenever possible. And if you are a WPF programmer, carefully read [Finding Memory Leaks in WPF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications/); this article has "saved my life" a dozen times.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to do this?  The garbage collector will collect the garbage when it feels like it.  It is often a bad idea to try to manage memory manually in C#.

That said, you could try using the following little trick I use sometime when running benchmarks that I don't want to be interrupted by the GC (cleaning up all the memory freed from last benchmark) --

```
GC.Collect();  

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); 

GC.Collect(); 

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to call gc explicitly, but if you call

```
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

It will call GC explicitly throughout your code, don't forget to call GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); after GC.Collect().

WaitForPendingFinalizers does not always gives a better performance, it simply blocks until all objects in the finalisation queue have finalised. If you want those objects to be collected then you need call System.GC.Collect a second time.