# Do Tasks generated by TaskCompletionSource need to be Dispose()d?

Tags: .net, task, dispose, taskcompletionsource

I'm using `TaskCompletionSource` in my software to distribute network packets to `async`/`await` methods. So in my code, there are various points where the software needs to wait for a network packet getting demultiplexed from the receive handler and handed over to a method `async Wait()`. There can be many, many packets per second and I'm deciding if I want to push the packet to `TaskCompletionSource` or put it into a `Queue`. So, whenever theres no `TaskCompletionSource` I will create a new one, which leads to a new `Task` object.

According to this question [Do I need to dispose of a Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985973) and according to this blog [Parallel Programming with .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/25/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) `Task`s don't need be `Dispose`d. However, I'm sometimes instantiating many thousand `TaskCompletionSource` per second. The detailed answer in the linked blog also says, that `Task` may use internally `WaitHandle`. Now I have the strong feeling that my case is the exact case, where I should use `Dispose` on the tasks from the `TaskCompletionSource`.

This is how I wait for a new packet. This method will be calles with `await` and can also be called heavily in parallel:

```
public async Task<Packet> Wait()
{
    Packet packet;

    lock (sync)
        if (packets.TryDequeue(out packet))
            return packet;
        else
            waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<Packet>();

    return await waiter.Task;
}
```

My method of pushing packets from the network handler looks like this:

```
public void Poke(Packet packet)
{
    lock (sync)
        if (waiter == null)
            packets.Enqueue(packet);
        else
            waiter.SetResult(packet);
}
```

I'm on .NET Core >= 2.2. The blog entry states that the behavior of `WaitHandle` also changed in .NET 4.5.

**Question: Do I need to Dispose `Task`s in this specific scenario? Will I create many `Handles`, if I don't `Dispose` the Tasks created by `TaskCompletionSource` when receiving many packets coming along this code path? Is this the scenario the blog entry warned me about?**

*Please refrain from telling me, that this method is a bad choice as long as you can't tell me a better method being very compatible to `async`/`await` pattern and also being able to distribute those packets to various selected listeners. Please also don't tell me, that creating many objects because of many network packets is generally a bad idea.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this the scenario the blog entry warned me about?

The question of "do I need to dispose this `Task`?" can only be answered by how the task is *consumed*. In particular, consider this quote from the blog post:

> the only way the WaitHandle will be allocated is if you explicitly ask for the Task’s IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, and that should be quite rare.

[Reed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985973) was true at the time, but it's no longer the case that continuations use `AsyncWaitHandle`. These days, nothing will use `AsyncWaitHandle` implicitly, so you should only consider `Dispose`ing `Task`s if *your consuming code* is treating the task as an `IAsyncResult` *and* accessing the `AsyncWaitHandle` property. And even then, you should only *consider* disposing them; it's not strictly *necessary*.

> Please refrain from telling me, that this method is a bad choice as long as you can't tell me a better method being very compatible to async/await pattern and also being able to distribute those packets to various selected listeners.

I would recommend building an async-compatible producer/consumer queue as a separate type; I think this would help your code be clearer. You could [use `BufferBlock<T>`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html), an [async queue type from my AsyncEx library](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/async-producer-consumer-queue-2-more.html), or build your own using an async-compatible monitor.

Also, if you regularly expect your `Wait()` method to already have a packet available, then consider using `ValueTask<T>`.