# How to create an instance of System.IO.Stream stream

Tags: c#, memory, stream

How to create an instance of `System.IO.Stream stream`. One of my function receives `System.IO.Stream stream` as parameter and write some thing to it. So how can I create a new instance of the same and pass it to the function ?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
```

Comment: Do we have to call Close or Dispose on such "empty" stream?

Comment: Short answer:  Yes.  For the longer answer, check out John Skeet's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/234257/1480854

Answer (score 26):

You have to create an instance of one of the subclasses.  `Stream` is an abstract class that can't be instantiated directly.

There are a bunch of choices if you look at the bottom of the reference here:

[Stream Class | Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx#inheritanceContinued)

The most common probably being `FileStream` or `MemoryStream`.  Basically, you need to decide where you wish the data backing your stream to come from, then create an instance of the appropriate subclass.

Answer (score 26):

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
```

you can use MemoryStream

Reference: [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Stream is a base class, you need to create one of the specific types of streams, such as MemoryStream.