# convert array of bytes to bitmapimage

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, bitmapimage

I'm going to convert array of bytes to `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` and show the `BitmapImage` in an image control.

When I'm using the first code, noting happens! no error and no image is displayed. But when I'm using the second one it works fine! can anyone say what is going on?

first code is here:

```
public BitmapImage ToImage(byte[] array)
{
   using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(array))
   {
       BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
       image.BeginInit();
       image.StreamSource = ms;
       image.EndInit();
       return image;
   }
}
```

second code is here:

```
public BitmapImage ToImage(byte[] array)
{
   BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
   image.BeginInit();
   image.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(array);
   image.EndInit();
   return image;
 }
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In the first code example the stream is closed (by leaving the `using` block) before the image is actually loaded. You must also set [BitmapCacheOptions.OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx) to achieve that the image is loaded immediately, otherwise the stream needs to be kept open, as in your second example.

```
public BitmapImage ToImage(byte[] array)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(array))
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; // here
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
}
```

From the Remarks section in [BitmapImage.StreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx):

> Set the CacheOption property to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad if you wish
>   to close the stream after the BitmapImage is created.

---

Besides that, you can also use built-in type conversion to convert from type `byte[]` to type `ImageSource` (or the derived `BitmapSource`):

```
var bitmap = (BitmapSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(array);
```

ImageSourceConverter is called implicitly when you bind a property of type `ImageSource` (e.g. the Image control's `Source` property) to a source property of type `string`, `Uri` or `byte[]`.

Comment: You mentioned a very good point about `CacheOption`, but in your code, the `MemroyStream` still will be disposed before the image is being loaded. Unless the call to `EndInit()` loads the image. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` does. The image is loaded synchronously during `EndInit`. Hence the stream will *not* be disposed before the image is loaded.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know that point about `CacheOption`. I changed my code and it works.

Comment: I was hoping this was JWTDO, but in a Windows Store App, I get, "Error 1 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInit' and no extension method 'BeginInit' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' could be found (are you missing a using..."

Comment: Windows Runtime and WPF are two different frameworks. There is no BeginInit and EndInit in Windows Runtime. Just call [SetSourceAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, you defined your `MemoryStream` in a `using` block, which causes the object to be disposed when you go out of the block. So you return a `BitmapImage` with a disposes (and non-existing) stream.

`MemoryStream`s keep no unmanaged resources, so you can leave the memory and let the GC handle the freeing process (but that's not a good practice).

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234071/1136211) about not disposing of a MemoryStream. It's at least considered bad practice.

Comment: @Clemens Thank for your comments and your nice answer.