# Converting Byte to Bitmap image

Tags: c#, database, bitmap, byte

I am getting the byte in database but I cannot convert it to bitmap, I got an exception in Parameter. This is what I've done so far.

```
con.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString;
con.Open();
OdbcCommand cmds = new OdbcCommand("Select ID from try where kalabaw = 5", con);
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmds);
byte[] image = (byte[])cmds.ExecuteScalar();
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(image);
pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
con.Close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337071/convert-array-of-bytes-to-bitmapimage

Comment: i cant pass the executeSalar to the method

Comment: there is no executescalar in the link I sent you

Comment: Why don't you try to create a memory stream around your byte [] and use Bitmap.FromStream(imageStream);

Comment: hehe sorry i am totally beginner

Answer (score 0):

I totally stole this answer from [convert array of bytes to bitmapimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337071/convert-array-of-bytes-to-bitmapimage)

```
public BitmapImage ToImage(byte[] array)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(array))
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; // here
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below.  I expect it should work.

```
byte[] bytes = GetBytesArrayFromDatabase();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    ms.Position = 0;
    Bitmap obj = new Bitmap(ms);

    // use the Bitmap object `obj` here
}
```