# How to get BitmapImage from byte array in several different ImageFormats

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have saved images in our database by using the following method to convert them to byte arrays in different ImageFormats:

```
public byte[] foo()
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
    var tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
    ImageFormat format = img.RawFormat;
    img.Save(tmpStream, format);
    tmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var imgBytes = new byte[MAX_IMG_SIZE];
    tmpStream.Read(imgBytes, 0, MAX_IMG_SIZE);
    return imgBytes;
}
```

Now I need to read them out and convert them back into the BitmapImage type so I can display them to the user. I was thinking about using the Image.FromStream(Stream) method but that doesn't seem to take into account the different ImageFormats... Anyone know what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC, Image.FromStream should automatically detect the image format.  Do you need to do anything special with it based on its format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert array of bytes to bitmapimage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337071/convert-array-of-bytes-to-bitmapimage)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use classes from the WinForms `System.Drawing` namespace in a WPF application (like you do with `Image.FromFile`).

WPF provides its own set of classes to load and save bitmaps from Streams and URIs, and has built-in support for automatically detecting the format of a bitmap frame buffer.

Just create a `BitmapImage` or a `BitmapFrame` directly from a Stream:

```
public static BitmapSource BitmaSourceFromByteArray(byte[] buffer)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    bitmap.Freeze(); // optionally make it cross-thread accessible
    return bitmap;
}
```

or

```
public static BitmapSource BitmaSourceFromByteArray(byte[] buffer)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(
            stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

Either method returns a `BitmapSource`, which is the base class of BitmapImage and BitmapFrame, and should be sufficient to deal with bitmaps in the rest of your application. E.g. the `Source` property of an Image control uses another base class, `ImageSource`, as property type.

Note also that when you load a BitmapSource from a Stream that is to be closed after loading, you have to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`. Otherwise the Stream must be kept open until the bitmap is eventually shown.

---

For encoding a BitmapSource you should be using a method like this:

```
public static byte[] BitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); // or any other BitmapEncoder

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```