# wpf documentviewer throws exception on mouse over image

Tags: wpf, image, exception, mouse, documentviewer

I have a fixeddocument in which i have an image. The source-property of the image is bound to a byte-array (read from the database) in the datacontext of the document. When I am moving the mouse over the image I get a filenotfoundexception.

It looks like the documentviewer tries to load additional information about the rendered image from a file named "image" in the working directory which of course does not exist.

Does somebody know how to disable this behavior?

Comment: We need more info about your issue, most importantly how you assign the image to the control. I generally use a converter and transform byte array to a bitmap and return that for an image control.

Comment: currently the source-property of the image is bound directly to the byte-array:

   
      <Image Margin="330 80 0 0"
             Width="132.2832"
             Height="170.0784"
             Source="{Binding PassPhoto}"  />


        public byte[] PassPhoto
        {
            get { return this.person.PassPhoto; }
        }
    
i will try your solution...

Comment: Try using a converter and transform that byte array to a bitmap. [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555447/2029607)

Comment: converting the byte-array into a bitmap did not work (image was not shown) but converting to a ImageSource did it. thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Did you set the cache option to `OnLoad` for the bitmap? Like [this post shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14337202/2029607).

Comment: no i did not. if i do it works like a charme too

Comment: @XAMlMAX Why write an answer when you already link to a duplicate question in a comment?

Comment: @Hurby Which version of WPF are you using? There should be built-in automatic type conversion from `byte[]` to `ImageSource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BitmapImage from a byte array with the following converter:

```
public class BytesToBitmapConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var bytes = (byte[])value; // make sure it is an array beforehand

        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.StreamSource = ms;
            image.EndInit();
            return image;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml you would use this like so:

```
<Image Source="{Binding propertyNameHere, Converter={StaticResource converterName}}"/>
```