# Image Control not showing the webcam frames captured using OpenCVsharp

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv

I have Written the Code below in my XAML code behind to show webcame frames Received as `Mat` with Opencvsharp `VideoCapture.Read()` method in my Image Control named `View`.

```
Mat mat = new Mat();
VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(2);

while (true)
{
    videoCapture.Read(mat);
    viewer.Source = mat.ToBitmapImage();
    if (btn_stop.IsPressed)
    {
        break;
    }
}
videoCapture.Release();
```

As u can see I used a converter to convert form Mat to BitmapImage so I can use it as image Source of my control. here are the Converters I used:

```
static class Converters
{
    public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bi.StreamSource = ms;
        bi.EndInit();
        bi.Freeze();
        return bi;
    }

    public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this Mat mat)
    {
        return BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(mat).ToBitmapImage();
    }
}
```

Simply this code shows nothing in my image control and the app is freezed. I know that this code is generating too much garbage and I can't do anything about it. Any ideas about my problem? i Also changed my code with the instructions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337071/convert-array-of-bytes-to-bitmapimage) link like below:

```
viewer.Source = (BitmapSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(mat.ToBytes());
```

and also these converters:

```
public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this Mat mat)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mat.ToBytes());
            image.EndInit();
            return image;
        }

public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this Mat mat)
        {
            using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mat.ToBytes()))
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.StreamSource = ms;
                image.EndInit();
                return image;
            }
        }
```

none of these worked for me.

Comment: Also set `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`

Comment: @Clemens I used all the instructions u and others mentiond on the link you set that my question is exact duplicate of! none of them worked for me. i will edit my question and write the changes!

Comment: Your `while (true)` loop is blocking the UI thread. Use a timer instead, e.g. a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: yes it worked.Tnx @Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres the answer according to [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens)'s comment:
Simply insantiate a `DispatcherTimer` object in `MainWindow`'s constructor and use the `Tick` event to update the UI:

```
DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();  
Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;  
Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30);  
Timer.Start();

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (videoCapture.Read(frame))
    {
        view.Source = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapSourceConverter.ToBitmapSource(frame);
    }
}
```