# Access File in memory stream ? c#

Tags: c#, memorystream

I'm using this code to save a file to memory stream

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Dictionary<string,MemoryStream> dict = new Dictionary<string,MemoryStream>();

dict.Add("mypicture.png",new MemoryStream());

bmp.Save(dict["mypicture.png"], ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

After that I have a function that accepts this file name

```
result = DrawMatches.Draw("box.png", "mypicture.png", out matchTime,i);
```

Am I accessing the file from a memory stream correctly?
in the function it's saying

> invalid argument

I think I'm not accessing the file in a correct way from the memory stream

this is the Drawmatches.Draw:

```
public static Image<Bgr, Byte> Draw(String modelImageFileName, String observedImageFileName, out long matchTime,int i)
{
   Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(modelImageFileName);
   Image<Gray, Byte> observedImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(observedImageFileName);
}
```

error is not in compilation, it is when running

it says " parameter is not valid " and points to the observedimage

Comment: Please post the code implementing your `DrawMatches.Draw` method, and the **exact** error message you are receiving. Also note whether it is a compile-time error, or a run-time error.

Comment: Also, I note that you do not actually save the drawing to a file. Did you intend to? It's a bit confusing what your intention is...

Comment: You never saved the file to disk, so if you ever need to use the image in your own function, consider directly accepting an `Image` object or a byte array containing the image. Trying to use a file name will never work.

Comment: It's related to this, I remember him asking about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562094/c-sharp-save-a-picture-file-to-ram

Comment: i saved it to ram , i know

Comment: but how can i use it now?

Comment: What is `Image<T, U>`?

Comment: @AlvinWong: Google says it's part of EMGU.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what the `Image<Gray, byte>` class is and how it is implemented, but you're passing a `string` to its constructor - are you sure that this is correct? (**EDIT**: Just found out it is part of the [EMGU](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Color_and_Depth_Conversion) implementation). I'll show you how you'd normally create an image from the stream:

```
MemoryStream ms = dict["mypicture.png"]; // This gives you the memory stream from the dictionary
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Go to the beginning of the stream
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms); // Create image from the stream
```

Now I suspect you want to create a new "emgu image" from the stream you have using the following constructor:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("MyImage.jpg");
```

Which is - according to the EMGU documentation - supposed to read an image from a *file*. You don't have a *file* named "mypicture.png", you have a *stream within a dictionary under the key "mypicture.png"*, which is something totally different. I doubt that the `Image<t1, t2>` class is able to read from a stream - at least I didn't see anything like that in the docs.

What you need to call is (using the code I provided above):

```
Image<Gray, Byte> img1 = new Image<Gray, Byte>(bmp);
```

All that being said, the code for the `Draw` method (which then can't be static, by the way) should read like this:

```
private Bitmap GetBitmapFromStream(String bitmapKeyName)
{
    MemoryStream ms = dict[bitmapKeyName];
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new Bitmap(ms);
}

public Image<Bgr, Byte> Draw(String modelImageFileName, String observedImageFileName, out long matchTime,int i)
{
   Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(GetBitmapFromStream(modelImageFileName));
   Image<Gray, Byte> observedImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(GetBitmapFromStream(observedImageFileName));
}
```

**EDIT**
In the comments below you say that you want to reduce the processing time by saving the bitmaps into a memory stream instead of writing to the disk.

I need to ask you the following: Why do you do that in the first place? I notice from the code you posted above that obviously you already have a `Bitmap` which you save into the memory stream. Why don't you put the bitmap itself into the dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, Bitmap> dict = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
dict.Add("mypicture.png", bmp);
```

Then you could retrieve it right away with even less time being wasted for storing and reading the image from the stream. The `Draw` method then would read:

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> Draw(String modelImageFileName, String observedImageFileName, out long matchTime,int i)
{
   Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(dict[modelImageFileName);
   Image<Gray, Byte> observedImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(dict[observedImageFileName]);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much thorsten
but you know, my function only accepts the file name
and i want to call the file directly from the memory stream
i dont want to make it a file 
bcoz im doing image processing and turning into file and saving it to the disk is going to take time which i dont want
so how can i call directly from ram ? by file name

Comment: please how can i talk to you ?

Comment: You can not "call a file directly from a memory stream". A file is a file and a memory stream is an area in the computer's memory. If your function only accepts names of files on the hard disk, then you need to create a file on the hard disk. Also, I've shown you the code you can use to access to create EMGU images from a memory stream. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Well actually i could have done this without the memory stream
ill save to the disk, then enter the file to the function
but when processing 100 images , it takes alot of time to save 100 images to disk
and it takes less time to save 100 images to ram ( i suppose ?)
thats why im trying to use the memory stream
my goal is to reduce the processing time , and saving 100 images takes alot of time , and time is important in my application
how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Fact is: what you're asking can simply not be done the way you implemented it. Period. The constructor for `Image<t1, t2>` expects either a `Bitmap` or the file name of an image file - a **file** name, not the string key of a stream in a dictionary. How in the world should the constructor know that it is supposed to access your dictionary (which it can't by the way) and get the stream?